# Uniform interpolation on a Cubic Hermite Spline

Tags: interpolation, spline, hermite-polynomials

I have a 3D spline with points $p_0,p_1,...,p_n$ and tangents $m_0,m_1,...,m_n$. I'm using the formula described in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline).

$p(t) = (2t^3-3t^2+1)p_0+(t^3-2t^2+t)m_0+(-2t^3+3t^2)p_1+(t^3-t^2)m_1$, where $t \in [0,1]$.

It seems that this spline doesn't have a constant speed, and the distances between uniformly sampled points are not uniform.

Is there anyway to make this interpolation uniform?

Answer (score 0):

No. The only polynomial curves that have constant speed are straight lines. For details, [see this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016783969190040I) paper by Rida Farouki.